# How to convert date to string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert javascript date to string but it's not working, i have a date like `2023-07-05` How to change it to `27 march 2023` please help me

Comment: You can use Intl APIs to do that. Please lookup MDN docs

Comment: Specifically at MDN, [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse for Date related questions of that kind.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Date Object and it's functions to achieve this task.

```
// Online Javascript Editor for free
// Write, Edit and Run your Javascript code using JS Online Compiler

// Create a new Date object with the original date
let date = new Date('2022-02-12'); // add any date here

let day = date.getDate();
let month = date.getMonth();
date.setMonth(month);

// Format the date as a string as required here (DD Month YYYY)
let newDate = day + ' ' + date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }) + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
console.log(newDate);
```